# I am having difficulties installing Ubuntu, I get a black screen with a flashing underscore

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 to my secondary hard drive, but whenever I select "install ubuntu" or "try ubuntu without installing" it goes to a black screen with what looks to be a flashing underscore. No matter how long I leave it it does not progress any further.

A video I just took of it happening: youtu.be/QMf2DrXu858

What am I doing something wrong? How may I fix it? I feel like the problem rests in my graphics card.

Should I try installing it via Wubi? Could I later turn that into a full install?

If it matters, my set up:

i5 2400k 3.1ghz

8gb DDR3 1333mhz RAM

2tb Seagate   /    500gb WD Caviar Blue

NVidia EVGA 550ti 1gb video RAM

Asus MOBO

Comment: Are you installing from CD?  Do an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the ISO.

Comment: Or try Ubuntu without installing and then try to install. 
Mitch is right, you should do that first.

(If you have one, you should use Unetbootin to put the ISO in a usb pen.)

Comment: Yes, I'm installing from a CD. I can't seem to find the MD5 of Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit edition. Does anybody have it so I can check to see if mine is correct? It looks like the MD5 I have is 128F0C16F4734C420b0185A492D92E52

Comment: @AlecRitter Yes, that's [the correct MD5 sum for that ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/MD5SUMS). What happens when you [check for corruption](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html) on the CD/DVD/USB flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the CD you're using, maybe it's not clean.
Or try installing it with an USB which is better than CD's

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, I have actually tried it on multiple disks so I don't think that is the problem. If you have the time, how would I go about making a bootable flash drive? And how big would it need to be?

Comment: you only have to download the .iso at the** ubuntu's page**. and to make it, it depends of the operating sistem you're using, if it's ubuntu, you can make iit in **Start Up Disk Creator**. but if you're still using windows, you'll have many options, (the one I used is ** Universal-USB-Installer**;you got to follow the instruccions. the third step is to install it.